# how can i host activex control to web form (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, com, activex, components

I have an activeX control and i need to work with it in web form in asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check:

[How to host ActiveX controls in a Web form](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317392)